# How to return the total count of a database entity when one of its rows matches a condition

Tags: python, python-2.7, sqlite

I have a list of numbers which I’m looping through to identify if an entity in a database table matches at least one of these numbers, if so, I want to count how many times these entities appear in that table and return the entities along with the number of time they a in the table. As the entities may match one or more numbers, I can just the duplicate data by using pythons set(), unless obviously there’s are better way to do it.

So for example

```
List  = [a, b, c, d]  # Unknown number of entries


Column 1    Column 2   column3 etc

Blue            a
Blue            -
Blue            a

Green           -
Red             a
Red             b
Red             c
Red             c
Red             -
Red             -
```

So im trying to return:

```
Blue, 3
Red, 6
```

The closest I've been able to get is below, but is not yielding the desired resutls.

```
for letter in list:

    c.execute('SELECT  colour, COUNT(*) FROM table GROUP BY colour HAVING letter=?', [(letter)])
```

I'm not sure how to proceed with this, any advice would be very much be appreciated.

In responce to @CL.

This was the kind of data that it was returning. The later nest in the list contains the correct values, but then the first nest contains “random” values.  I can’t understand how these are formed so I’m unsure how to remove them.

```
[[(red, 1), (anotherColour, 1)], [(red, 6), (blue, 3), (anotherColour, 5) ]]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, get the entities that you want to count:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT colour
FROM MyTable
WHERE letter IN ('a', 'b', 'c', 'd')
```

Then, use that to filter the entities before counting:

```sql
SELECT colour,
       COUNT(*)
FROM MyTable
WHERE colour IN (SELECT colour
                 FROM MyTable
                 WHERE letter IN ('a', 'b', 'c', 'd'))
GROUP BY colour
```

When you have an unknown number of entries, you have to construct the parameter list dynamically:

```py
list = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
params = ','.join('?' for _ in list)
c.execute("""SELECT colour,
                    COUNT(*)
             FROM MyTable
             WHERE colour IN (SELECT colour
                              FROM MyTable
                              WHERE letter IN (""" + params + """))
             GROUP BY colour""",
          list)
```

Comment: give distinct color  for inner query

Comment: DISTINCT is superfluous for the temporary index that SQLite constructs for the IN lookup.

Comment: [It's not needed](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/superfluous); SQLite would just ignore it.

Comment: Thank you CL.  However, for some reason, although it returns the correct result, it also returns other values for the colours in a nested list.  I'll add an example of what I mean to my original post.

Comment: And me! :D Thank you.  Sorry about that, it was because I some other code, from attempts at solving this problem (so the data looked simular) being appended to the list.  So that was my fault. But thank you very much.